# MVC Entry for every User C#

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, entry-point

I want to take a look at it and build a small intranet with various applications

About the "global.asax" I have the entry serverside. That means for me, when I start the server, I can do my initializations for the server in the Application_Start() area.

Where can I make initializations for the user?
so I want to save all users who log on to the site in a singleton (and also other informationen). I'm also interested in the exit point (to delete data from singleton).

In the HomeController, I could grab the whole thing in every ActionResult, but that would be awkward. Is there no point to which "ALL" users have to pass?

Comment: You are talking about users, does that mean you have a login system? Then *that* would be your user entry point. If it is an anonymous app then what kind of information would you want to save?

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't mention that.

I use the WIndows Autentification in a Domain Network

Comment: Have you tried using session_onstart and session_onend in the global.asax file? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178583.aspx

Comment: wow thanks... it works ;) but if I closed the Browser the Method Session_OnEnd() does not triggerd...
is there another solution? e. g. a test if the user is online

Comment: One way you can do this is to implement [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) then you can poll from the server if the browser is still active or not